# how to configure maven to ignore the 'maven' folders in jar files

Tags: maven, maven-3

how to configure maven to ignore the 'maven' folders in jar files. I have added the jars I want manually to my local repo, however maven keeps failing due to these maven folders in jars. I can go in and delete the 'maven' folder from META-INF manually jar by jar and I make progress but it takes up significant time to do that to every jar file. Is there a setting to get maven to ignore these folders in jar files?

Comment: So you say you manually copied/moved jars to your local repository (without install:install-file)? Maven fails due to the Maven-folders in these jars? I think there's another problem. What kind of errors/stacktraces do you get?

Comment: these are third party jars I added to artifactory (local), they have a 'maven' folder in them (various sources), I have to manually remove them or maven searches for them and tries to find every jar listed by exact name in that folder

Comment: I can recall some issues with uploading files to artifactory and generating pom-files. However, I still don't understand the Maven issue here. Maven doesn't just search (it 'knows' which files it wants to download), and it doesn't look inside jars. Mevan first collects the pom-files, followed by the matching artifacts. So what's the real issue?

Comment: you don't know maven then, if I download say hibernate core it has a META-INF/maven folder in the jar. If you add that to say artifactory local before removing that folder from the jar you can run into issues

Comment: search my name ;) I'm *not* saying that jars don't contain a maven folder, I'm just saying that Maven doesn't use that file to decide which files should be downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if run mvn:dependency it brings up the list of jar files it will reference from this folder. I made it a habit of deleting this folder before every jar and they no longer show up in mvn:dependency is run and doesn't try to download them. It would be nice if they added a maven command to ignore these folders. Currently, there is no way to get maven to ignore them without deleting this folder. This is for anyone setting up maven repo on network not connecting to the internet - for example work place build which can not rely on insecure or ever changing internet repos